# How can i add delay to the show database values in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the values from the database to php, and i am calling the function in my html page.I want to display values with delay of 1 sec each so i am using `sleep()`. but,the `sleep()` is not working in php.

I am getting error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\mapapp\php\index.php on line 15
```

php:

```
function getCity_list(){
require_once "php/config.php";
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT id, city_name, latitude, longitude, state FROM city_list";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["city_name"].",". $row["state"]."<br>";
        sleep(1);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

}

how can i solve this?

Comment: i think you want to display the values in your browser with the 1 second delay, am i right? if so - this won't work anyway - the server will only respond to the http request once your page is rendered. for example if you got 100 values, then your page will be displayed after 100 seconds.

Comment: @low_rents yes, then any other possible way?

Comment: yes - javascript. you can render all the values into hidden `<div>`'s for example and then show them 1 by 1 (using pure javascript or jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Your script is getting a timeout error you can use `set_time_limit ( int $seconds )` to increase the time or just pass 0 for no timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the maximum execution time like this in your code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes // add your value here
```